# ImportError: No module named scenedetect on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use pyscenedetect library on python for videos but I get this error when using the python interface and when I use the command line interface I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'"

even though I believe I installed both correctly according to the documentations.

I have trying to look for different ways to import opencv for the second error but to no avail. As for the first error i can't find any answers to my problem.

```
import cv2
import numpy as numpy
import os

import scenedetect
from scenedetect.video_manager import VideoManager
from scenedetect.scene_manager import SceneManager
from scenedetect.frame_timecode import FrameTimecode
from scenedetect.stats_manager import StatsManager
from scenedetect.detectors import ContentDetector
```

Comment: What is the module `scene_detect` supposed to be? Shouldn't that be `scenedetect`?

Comment: yea sorry about that i was trying different names as a last resort type of solution. I edited the code snippet @M.Spiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. As Ivan was pointing out, the problem was with openCV.

I used the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip you can try

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If you have anaconoda, you can try

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

it's probable that you installed it on a different python installation in your PC.
To know where your python installation is you can launch python and:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

To get the list of everything you have installed you can:

```
pip freeze > installed_modules.txt
```

Try only running

```
import cv2
```

So that you can test it