# Which version of python and opencv are matched?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use openCV and python for my work.
But unable to find matched compatible versions of python and openCV.
I tried using python version 3.7, 3.6, it did nor worked.

I want to know more about python vs openCV version compatibility.
Please help me out.

Comment: There are many combinations between those. You probably have an installation problem. Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58561025/11261546) , several cases are cover in that answer

Comment: Please clarify what isn't working. Python 3.6 and 3.7 and latest opencv work fine. Scroll to bottom https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Hi cricket_007, thanks for your answer. I tried already with that but not working

Answer (score 1):

opencv supports python 3.7

Install python 3.7 with anaconda package and use this command to install opencv.

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Comment: whta about anaconda with python 3.6? I tried with that.

Comment: with 3.6 it should also be installed in the same way, may be there is some installation step you are missing, that's why it is not getting installed correctly on you environment

Comment: can you tell me some teaching url or tutorial site's url? thanks

Comment: which OS are you using ? linux, windows or mac ?

Comment: Windows 10, and if you have experience in using opencv, then please share yours like this. "I used python x.x and opencv x.x" Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest version of python (check here https://www.python.org/downloads/), along with pip3 (check here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Then for a specific version of OpenCV, for example the 4.1.2.30, you can run :

```
pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.2.30
```

Hope this helps.