# Pip does not install in USER_SITE

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, python-3.6

my specific problem is with pip 9.0.3 (no other version tested) on linux.
When I try to install a package for locally for my linux user using

```
$ pip3 install --user numpy
...
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.1
```

I get

```
$ python3 -m numpy
/usr/bin/python3: No module named numpy
```

As far as I know, pip3 should install in

```
$ python3 -m site
...
USER_BASE: '/home/username/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

but the directory is empty.
But what I've found are modules in `/home/username/.username/modules` which seems to be installed by pip3. 
How can I configure pip to use the correct USER_SITE?

**Q: Which pip/python is used?**

```
$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3 
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

**Q: how does sys.path looks like?**

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

**Q: Have you tried to upgrade your pip first?**
I have no super-user privileges on this machine (why I try to install in USER_SITE).

**Q: Do you have local configuration files like [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration)?**
The online doc describes pip 20.0.2 instead of 9.0.3 or similar. 
However, there are no such config files like

```
/home/username/.config/pip/pip.conf
/home/username/.pip/pip.conf
/etc/pip.conf
/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf
```

**Q: have you tried to install/upgrade in USER_SITE?**
Yes. But without the correct path, it will not work.

```
$ python3 -m pip install -U --user pip
...
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
$ which pip
~/.username/scripts/pip
$ pip --version 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/username/.username/scripts/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

Comment: * Which version of Pip is this? Have you tried upgrading your `pip` first?
* Are you sure that's the right `pip3` script? Does `python -m pip install --user numpy` work better?

Comment: can you check '`which pip3`' command

Comment: go through this link [configuration](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration).
Does this answer yourquestion?

Comment: If you launch `python3` than you `import sys` and display `sys.path`.. Are you in the right python? => [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58561025/11261546)

Comment: What if you try to upgrade Pip itself using `--user`? `python -m pip install -U --user pip`?

Comment: try to add your USER_SITE dir to PYTHONPATH, with something like `export PYTHONPATH=$(python3 -c "import site, os; print(os.path.join(site.USER_BASE, 'lib', 'python', 'site-packages'))"):$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I would recommend anyone to never ever use the `pip somecommand` script directly but to use the executable module instead `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand`. https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/